# std::getline doesn't skip empty lines when reading from ifstream

Tags: c++

Consider this code:

```
vector<string> parse(char* _config) {
  ifstream my_file(_config);
  vector<string> my_lines;
  string nextLine;
  while (std::getline(my_file, nextLine)) {
      if (nextLine[0] == '#' || nextLine.empty() || nextLine == "") continue;
      my_lines.push_back(nextLine);
  }
return my_lines;
}
```

and this config file:

```
#Verbal OFF
0

#Highest numeric value
100

#Deck
67D 44D 54D 63D AS 69H 100D 41H 100C 39H 10H 85H 7D 42S 6C 67H 61D 33D 28H 93S QH 5D 91C 40S 50C 74S 8C 98C 96C 71D 82S 75S 23D 40C 29S QC 84C 16C 80D 13H 35S

#Players
P1 1
P2 2
```

My goal is to parse the config file to a vector of strings, parsed line by line, ignoring empty lines and the '#' character.

When running this code on Visual Studio, the output is correct But, when running on Linux with g++, I still get some empty lines.

Comment: Are you sure those lines are empty, and don't perhaps contain spaces or tabs?

Comment: Inside the if statement `nextLine.empty()` should be the first condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your input file most likely has lines ending with `CR LF`, i.e. Windows/DOS text files. Linux expects all lines ending with `LF` only, so on Linux, `std::getline()` ends up reading a line containing a single `CR` character.

Before the existing code that checks the contents of `nextLine`, check if the line is non-empty, and ends with the `CR` character, then remove it. Then continue on with your existing `if` statement.